# How do I know if a char* buffer contains a monochrome image?

Tags: c, image-processing

I have images that are monochrome and images that aren't.

```
 unsigned char* buffer //represents the content of the image
```

and I want to do the following:

```
if monochromeImage
   do something
else
   do something else
```

but how can I tell that an image is monochrome according to its buffer?

Comment: What does "binarized" mean in this context?

Comment: it's a black and white only image

Comment: And how is a binarized image represented?

Comment: Do you know anything at all about the possible formats that might appear in this mysterious byte array? Do you know where the content comes from? How do you come to have it?

Comment: Actually I don't know, I just receive my byte array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

There is no inherent difference between a buffer contaning an image in 32-bit ARGB color and a monochrome image. Bytes are bytes, bits are bits.

However, you do have this information when the file is loaded and it would make sense to store it somewhere for later retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

The proper term for “binarized” would probably be “1-bit color depth” or “monochrome”. If you have control over image loading and storage, store a flag somewhere saying the image is monochrome. If you don’t, chances are the loading code already gives you some metadata about the image?